# Will all code 128 barcodes with the same number of characters & numbers have equal length?

Tags: barcode

I have a long list of identification codes and will use these to generate barcodes (code 128). All identification codes have the same number of characters and numbers (e.g. 1033_Rt__H_1). I need to know if the length of all these barcodes will be equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the pattern of letters, digits and punctuation does not change, the barcodes will be the same length.  Code128 has the ability to encode pairs of digits as single code words, so that is where variability in length can come into play when the format is not consistent.